# How to use nodejs's zlib to unzip GzipStream from API gateway?

Tags: javascript, node.js, .net, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Im using API gateway from AWS.
Data comein is the binary format from somebody's post request. And we know it is created by :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netframework-4.6

```
body: `\x1F�\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00��]o�0\x14���oG��\x0F\x02��t�&�\x1B"\x19�6��I��7'����\x10�}v\n` +`\x1F�\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00��]o�0\x14���oG��\x0F\x02��t�&�\x1B"\x19�6��I��7'����\x10�}v\n` 
    ....,
  isBase64Encoded: false
...
'Content-Type': 'application/gzip',
```

#### My current attempt

```js
const B = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(body, 'binary'));
// or const B = Buffer.from(body, 'binary'); not work

zlib.unzip(B, (err, buffer) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(buffer.toString());
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

And getting some err:

```js
Error: incorrect header check
    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (node:zlib:189:17) {
  errno: -3,
  code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR'
}
```

#### Expected

Unzip this data and parse to json with `zlib` from nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :

Reference this article, in setting of API gateway, enable this
[image]

https://techblog.commercetools.com/gzip-on-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-5170bb02b543

Answer (score 1):

Try `zlib.gunzip` instead. Your data is a gzip stream, not a zlib stream.

Comment: Tried, still incorrect header check.

Comment: I hope you're not trying to copy and paste that string with white question marks in black hexagons. Each one of those would then be a corrupted byte.

Comment: Solved it, turns out it this AWS API gateway's problem, I have to enable binary option...